# Simplicial Sets, Simplicial Monoids, and Simplicial Free Monoids

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

What is the difference between simplicial sets and simplical monoids? Does there exist an adjunction between these two structures? Does there exist a simplicial free monoid over some set which in turn could become a simplicial set? Is there an adjunction here? What happens if I define an order on the vertices of these simplices?

Comment: Do you know the definition of simplicial set?

Comment: @KevinCarlson it is a sequence of sets $K_n$, $n\geq0$, and functions $d_i:K_n\to K_{n-1}$ (face map) and $s_i:K_n\to K_{n+1}$ (degeneracy map) for $0\leq i\leq n$ that satisfy its identities. (hopefully...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simplicial whatever is a sequences of whatevers with whatever morphisms as you described in the comments, in particular, this works if the whatevers are sets or monoids. There are many adjunctions among the categories of sets, monoids, simplicial sets, and simplicial monoids coming from the theory of Kan extensions. The simplest relevant to your questions are the free simplicial monoid on a simplicial set, which simply takes the free monoid on each $K_n$ with induced face and degeneracy maps, which is left adjoint to the obvious forgetful functor from simplicial monoids to simplicial sets, and the discrete simplicial set on a a set, which has all $K_n$ equal with faces and degeneracies identities, and is left adjoint to the functor sending a simplicial set to its $K_0$. In particular by composition we get a free simplicial monoid on a set, which is the same as the discrete simplicial monoid on the free monoid on the set.

Comment: So then how about order?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, are the morphisms now supposed to be order preserving? I know this is done in certain contexts but I have nothing general to say about it.

Comment: I do mean order preserving

Comment: So just ask for all the sets to be ordered, and the faces and degeneracies to be order preserving.

Comment: Then how about the monoid structure? Same thing?

Comment: I think I already answered that in the first sentence.